# Dot prefix on cookie domain preventing CORS request

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, cookies, cors

When I send a response from my server after authentication, I'm setting an authentication token cookie in the client's browser using this header:

`Set-Cookie:mysite_auth=encodedJwtHere.JustPretend; SameSite=lax; domain=subdomain.mydomain.com; HTTPOnly; Max-Age=600; Secure; path=/`

However, when I open EditThisCookie in Chrome, I can see that the domain is being set to `.subdomain.mydomain.com` automatically.

From what I thought I understood, this shouldn't be an issue. When I request `https://subdomain.mydomain.com` in the browser, the cookie is being sent.

My issue happens when I try to make a CORS request. I'm developing a javascript app and serving it on `localhost`. When I make an AJAX call to `https://subdomain.mydomain.com`, the cookie is not sent.

I have all of the proper headers set on the response:

`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type, *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`

I have the `{withCredentials:true}` config on my request.

If I open `https://subdomain.mydomain.com` in the browser, then with EditThisCookie, I remove the prefix dot, I.E. I change `.subdomain.mydomain.com` to `subdomain.mydomain.com`, suddenly my AJAX calls from localhost work. The cookie is sent with the request.

So my question is, first of all, why is the cookie not being sent when there is a prefix dot, and is there a way to resolve this issue without manually editing the domain every time my cookie is refreshed?

Comment: Actually it seems the dot has nothing to do with it. If I open EditThisCookie and simply click the save button, the cookie then is sent on all subsequent requests. There is something preventing the cookie from being sent on CORS requests until after I manually update the cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sending credentials, you can't respond with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` - you must respond with a value that EXACTLY mirrors the Origin request header, e.g. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {value-of-Origin-Header}`.

In your case, that would presumably be `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://subdomain.mydomain.com`. Best not to hard-code it though - just mirror back Origin value.